# How to correctly use WebDriverWait & presence_of_element_located() in 2023?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Here is the HTML I am detecting:

```
<div class="arrowPopup arrowPopup-start">
    <div class="arrowPopupText arrowPopupTextTwoLine arrowPopupText-flashOn" style="white-space: nowrap;">type<br>this</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'arrowPopup arrowPopup-start')))
```

This does not work and times out after 20 seconds.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it does. This is straight out of [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits),

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
```

My guess is that your locator is incorrect or the element is in an IFRAME but we don't have enough info to determine for sure.

---

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20) # may need to adjust this based on how much time it takes to get a full game
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Enter a Typing Race']"))).click();
textToType = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[./span[@unselectable]]"))).text;
typeHere = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'txtInput')][not(@disabled)]")));
for character in textToType
    typeHere.send_keys(character);
    Thread.Sleep(50); # adjust this to change the typing speed
```

Since you asked for a breakdown of this XPath

```
//input[contains(@class,'txtInput')][not(@disabled)]
^ starting at the top of the DOM, find any INPUT
       ^ whose class contains the text 'txtInput'
                                    ^ but does NOT contain the attribute 'disabled'
```

Comment: I added the HTML I am trying to detect in the main post, can you take a quick look ?

Comment: https://play.typeracer.com/                  I am trying to detect the green flags that appear once the race has started.   I think there is an iframe the first time I click "inspect element", then I click "Inspect element" again, and see the DIV.   Could that be it ?

Comment: Could I look for this instead?    <div class="gameStatusLabel">The race is on! Type the text below:</div>

Comment: I looked at the site. Don't worry about detecting the flag, instead wait for the INPUT that you type in to become enabled (not disabled), CSS selector `input.txtInput`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a short script that works. When I tested it, it was typing ~180 wpm. NOTE: While this may be a fun side project, my guess is that if you use this regularly you will get banned from the site. No one wants to race a script...

Comment: Ha, yes, thanks, this was just a fun way to learn Browser automation with a little "wow" factor, due to the visual feedback.  I do not plan on actually using it.    I will use your alternate trigger, but I had it working in 2020, by using the green flags, and kinda annoyed that no longer works.

Comment: Got an error when using your code.    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Here is the line:   typeHere = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//input[contains(@class,'txtInput')][not(@disabled)]")));

Comment: I changed it to this:   Note the comma separated arguments with double (( ))'s

Comment: typeHere = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'txtInput')][not(@disabled)]")));

Comment: Where can I learn what this code means:   (By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'txtInput')][not(@disabled)]")));

Comment: My original way was much more obvious.  ((By.CLASS_NAME, "myclassname"))

Comment: B/c your way is not even the actual XPATH, it's some sort of code logic embedded as a parameter

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I primarily do C# so I formatted the locators incorrectly. I think I've got them all fixed now.

Comment: I've added some description of the XPath you asked about.

Comment: `My original way was much more obvious. ((By.CLASS_NAME, "myclassname"))` Yes, but we need to wait for the INPUT to become enabled so we can start typing. By adding the `[not(@disabled)]` we accomplish that with the locator which is faster than repeatedly hitting the page, grabbing the element, and then checking if it's disabled.

Comment: `B/c your way is not even the actual XPATH, it's some sort of code logic embedded as a parameter`. No, that's actually an XPath. XPath has some methods/functions. You can read more about them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions, including `not()`.

Comment: Did the updated code work for you?

Comment: Hey @JeffC, I really want to thank you for taking the time to help a complete stranger online.    I did get your code to work, so my demo is working, thanks to you.  However, it still annoys me that I could not figure out why my original wait command did not work:   #element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'arrowPopup arrowPopup-end')))

Comment: The green popup arrows coincided with the textbox being enabled, so it should have worked.   It did work in the past.   Start typing when the green arrows appear.

Comment: I also was hoping to get my BY_CLASS identifier method working instead of using the more complicated XPATH "macro"

Comment: So the `(By.CLASS_NAME, 'arrowPopup arrowPopup-end')` locator is not valid because CLASS_NAME expects a single class name and you've actually passed it 2, "arrowPopup" and "arrowPopup-end". You can either remove one of the classes (assuming it will work without both) or you can convert that locator to a CSS selector, `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.arrowPopup.arrowPopup-end')`. A preceeding "." in a CSS selector indicates a class name.

Comment: Yup, that did it!    What's the advantage of using CSS_SELECTOR vs. CLASS_NAME ?

Comment: Hey, I Read your SO bio.   You're old school from the 80s and still rocking the coding.   Such history in one mind, impressive.  You're truly a selfless guy helping people online.  A true scholar.  Thank you again

Comment: On another note, I thought you would find this interesting.    Recall the part about getting the text that will be typed?  You did it this way:  textToType = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[./span[@unselectable]]"))).text;

Comment: However, when you look at that elements XPATH, you will see some sort of array at the very end.   I think they break up the text to type into a few chunks?   The foil bots like we are writing?    The XPATH looks like this, but the last array size varies from [2] to [3] sometimes [4]  ........  Xp = '//*[@id="gwt-uid-20"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/div/span[3]'

Comment: You got around that by matching the span name <span unselectable="on">   and using ((By.XPATH, "//div[./span[@unselectable]]"))).text;

Comment: You're "Coding" the XPATH, while I am just copying the literal XPATH by right clicking.    Your way is superior, since I had to reassemble the array of [3] text elements back into a single string

Comment: How did you know to do //div[./span[] and not just span[] ?

Comment: CSS_SELECTOR vs. CLASS_NAME, class name ONLY does a single class name. CSS selectors can find just about any element short of things like locating an element by contained text like XPath does.

Comment: Yes, handcrafted XPaths (or really any locator) are superior but it takes time to build the knowledge to build them. Copy/pasted XPaths, etc. from the browser tools many times are filled with bad practices and things that are likely to break with even minor page changes. I learned all this stuff the hard way over years of writing automation. Try something, it eventually breaks. Read more articles, try more things, and slowly build experience and knowledge to hopefully make locators that are less fragile.

Comment: `//div[./span[@unselectable]]` returns the DIV where `span[...]` returns the SPAN. I wanted the DIV. Basically `//div[./span[@unselectable]]` means return the DIV that has a child SPAN with the `unselectable` attribute.

Comment: I posted this in the private chat feature, as well

Comment: I think this is a private chat now. Never tried this feature
Yes, the hardcoded nature of the copy/paste XPATH is probably less robust than the less specific nature of div/span combo. Agreed on the locator learning curve, as well.
If I ever have another question, if there a way to direct msg you or email you? You are a true mentor type.

Comment: It's still a public chat. As far as I know, there is no private chat feature on SO. I think it would probably be abused too much.

Comment: If you're ok with it, can I email you a future Python question, if I ever do more with Selenium?  I won't abuse it, promise.   Can you email me at LotusEscalade@gmail.com ?